# How to backgroundGradientColour for individual components?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, stylesheet

I want to give different background gradient color for each component in my flex3 application.

For whole application we have like

```
Application {
   backgroundColor: #869ca7;
   backgroundGradientColors: #3366ff, #68808c;
}
```

But i want same thing to be done for each component with different set of colors? Is there any way other than using gradient background image?

Comment: Use a [Rect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Rect.html) to draw the gradient

Comment: In your subject line did you mean "individual"?

Comment: @RIAstar Thanks for your response, but i cant use Rect, because my project is a Flex 3 compatible one, so cant use spark themes

Comment: Please state that information in your question and/or tags.

Comment: @Veeru A S I believe you can use a border skin, example here: http://www.websector.de/blog/2007/07/04/skinning-flex-containers-using-wsdoubleborderskin/ You could use this page for examples on how to do a gradient fill: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Drawing_Vector_Graphics_6.html